# Encoding Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, encoding

I installed `zShell` on my Unbuntu 14.04.5 LTS. Now there is an encoding error:

[image]

How can I fix the `???` ?

Comment: You need to install fonts, pls take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238864/installing-powerline-fonts-for-zsh-prezto-theme

Comment: Does not work for me. Changed the font to `Powerline` but the `???` are still there.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

My locales were not set to UTF8. See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995089/lang-environment-variable-in-zsh).